# Using D3 zoom in JavaFX Webview

Tags: javascript, d3.js, webview, javafx, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX Webview which renders a graph (using D3). I want to implement the 'zoom on mouse scroll' on this graph in the JavaFX application (when the mouse is hovered on top of the webview). I was able to do it successfully on a web-browser using the following d3 js code

```html
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", zoomHandler))
    .append('g');


function zoomHandler() {
  svg.attr("transform",
      "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
      + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

but if I do something similar inside the JavaFX application's WebView, the graph is rendered initially in the WebView but on scroll, just disappears and only reappears if I bring back the mouse scroll to the initial position (when the application was started)

The following code is how I use WebView to render the graph

```html
        final URL urlLoadMainGraph = getClass().getResource("html/MainGraph.html");                
        weMainGraph.load(urlLoadMainGraph.toExternalForm());
```

Is there something wrong on what is being done ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide a solution, but i have the same problem.
The problem is, that you have not specified any scale.

JavaFX is just jumping from the minimum to the maximum scale of the zoom with one "tip" on the mousewheel :(. if you specify it in a certain range, it could work out for you. Use this for example to zoom a little bit outside.

```
 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height).call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.75, 1]);
```

best so far... hoping for anwsers!

(PS: i couldnt comment... thats why this kind of answer.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in your zoomhandler code example. You might want to start with a handler like the following and go on from there:

```
function zoomHandler() {
  alert('zoom');
}
```

Here is a more detailed d3 zoom example:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3892919

And here is a JavaFx wrapper for D3 that also contains a working zoom example:

https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/javafx-d3

https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/javafx-d3/blob/master/javafx-d3-demo/src/main/java/com/github/javafxd3/demo/client/democases/behaviors/ZoomDemo.java